# Heroku Error - Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: heroku, deployment, webpack

I keep getting this error when deploing to Heroku. Build process was succesfull but then I get this error. Can't figure out what is the problem and shouldn't path be src/server/views? Everything is working locally.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "src\server/views"
[web.1]:at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
app[web.1]:at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
app[web.1]:at Function.render(/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
app[web.1]:at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
app[web.1]:at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
app[web.1]:at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I use webpack tu bundle my server side code and I use html-webpack-plugin to inject my index.ejs template from views folder to webpack bundle.

**webpack.config.server.js**

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true
  },
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/server/prodServer.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(buildPath, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
...
  plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'ejs-loader!./src/server/views/index.ejs'
      })
    ]
```

**prodServer.js**

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
```

**folder structure**

as you can see I have index.ejs inside views folder. prodServer is my server file and after webpack build I get bundle file and index.html.

In Heroku start script I run node ./src/build/bundle.js

[image]

Comment: Ou, I just noticed that Heroku has add 'app' in fron of all my path. You can see it in error. Why is that?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer? I ran across the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It is because of how your __dirname is defined in Heroku.  If you run `heroku run bash` and then run `pwd` you will see that your current working directory is `/app`, hence why `/app` is added in front of all your paths.

Try to play around with the command `ls` in your bash to see if your server folder is listed, and then with a `cd server` command see if the `views` file is there as well.  Note that it is case sensitive, so most likely you had it defined in uppercase.

Also, note that it adds a `src\` (with a backward slash instead of forward slash) to your `src\server/views` path, which could be from a wrong configuration in your `webpack.config.server.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was enough to change the script from package.json `"start": "node app.js"`
to
`"start": "nodemon app.js"`