# Failed to lookup view "home/index" in views directory "/app/views"

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ejs

I am trying to publish my project to heroku to make it run in the cloud. Locally it works on port 5000, and i can get every view. When i upload it to heroku, i get the following error when i try to reach the home page: Failed to lookup view "home/index" in views directory "/app/views"

I already tried to do the following:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating
```

I also looked on the internet for other solutions, but nothing seems to fix my problem.

My route looks like this:

- views/home/index.ejs

The code that looks for the file is:

```
        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.render('home/index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
        });
```

The expected output is that my heroku is working fine without making big changes, so it can both work on heroku and locally. At the moment heroku is giving back the above error.

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710767/heroku-error-error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory

Comment: I got the same error. Were you able to figure out the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because Heroku can't find the sub-folder `home` inside the `views` folder.  This is very likely because you might have written the folder as 'Home' instead of 'home'.  To find out, do a `heroku run bash` and then run `ls`.  This will list the folders inside the /app folder.  Once inside the working directory, you should see the `views` folder.  do a `cd views` and you will have the list of all the folders.  There you should find the `home` folder.  If you find a `Views` instead of `views` or `Home` instead or no `home` at all, then that is where the error comes from since in heroku, folder and file paths are case sensitive (in local it is not and that is why you don't run into the same error in localhost port 5000).

Once you fix the folder and file names to the appropriate case, do a push on Heroku and it should work.  Also be careful to test again to see if in `heroku run bash` it worked, and the `cd home` works.  If it doesn't then you need to delete the `home` folder, push into Heroku and then repaste the `home` folder and do the push (because of cache) and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried app-module-path?

```
const path = require('path');
require('app-module-path').addPath(path.join(__dirname, '../'));


I do not possess any experience with Heroku but the error seems to be related with a 
path problem like assuming there is a different directory level.
I would try to debug it on the render method and then go for a module solution.
```

**For Example**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('../home/index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `res.render()`, use `res.sendFile()` instead.. as seen below

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/home/donnyllionaire/CRUD-app-Nodejs-Express-and-MongoDB/employee/addOrEdit.html'));
```

See this link for more clarification: https://github.com/donnillionaire/CRUD-app-Nodejs-Express-and-MongoDB/commit/11704d4572b7acc18b7289103b71282c58358d9a